# pyqt5 css setSheetStyle nested writing

Tags: css, python-3.x, pyqt5

recently I get a request that realize hover effect by using CSS in PyQt5, I dont know how to write nested writing, now present my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QAction, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette, QBrush, QPixmap


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()  

    def initUI(self):
        btn = QPushButton('button', self)

        button = QMenu()

        btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{color:black}"
                          "QPushButton:hover{color:red}"
                          "QPushButton{background-color:rgb(78,255,255)}"
                          "QPushButton{border:2px}"
                          "QPushButton{border-radius:10px}"
                          "QPushButton{padding:2px 4px}"
                          "QPushButton:hover{QMenu{display:block}}"
                          # "QMenu:!hover{display:block}"
                          # "#button:!hover{display:block}"
                          )

        # button.setStyleSheet("QMenu:!hover{display:None}")


        new_action = QAction("create", button)
      
        new_action.triggered.connect(lambda: print("file"))
        open_action = QAction("open", button)
        open_action.triggered.connect(lambda: print("open"))
        exit_action = QAction("quit", button)
        exit_action.triggered.connect(lambda: print("quit"))
        button.addAction(new_action)
        button.addAction(open_action)

        btn.setMenu(button)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`"QPushButton:hover{QMenu{display:block}}"`

This line not effect, so I wanna know how to make this line to effect and get the right writing, Thank you!

Comment: 1. Qt Style Sheets (QSS) are based on CSS2.1, which doesn't provide rule nesting; 2. children are styled following the [*descendant* or *child* selector](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) (ie: `parent child {...}`); 3. the pseudo state of the parent is *completely ignored*, so the child would be styled no matter of the parent "hover" state; 4. even considering the above, you should always ensure that the property is *actually* provided by the API: as the documentation shows, [`display` is not supported](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties).

Comment: So, considering the above, please explain what you're *actually* trying to achieve, as `display:block` doesn't seem to make a lot of sense for a menu, since all items are *always* shown on their own geometry, and generally vertically aligned.

Comment: Thank you, I just suspect that the descentdant or child selector is effect or not . In my projcet, I tried to use leveaEvent and enterEvent to achieve my goal, but it always lead to process break in some situation, So I try to using CSS to achieve this goal that show this child menu when my mouse hover or slide my pushbutton. – 
And by the way, I just tried to use `parent child {...})`, but not effect,                           `"QPushButton QMenu:hover{display:block}"`, maybe Im wrong writing@musicamante

Comment: As already said, please try to explain what your *real* purpose is. `display:block` is no-op, so it's really unclear what you're actually trying to achieve. I'm seriously under the impression that you may have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so, please, be more explicit and clear about your final purpose.

Comment: Sorry, `display:block` means that when the mouse covers QPushButton, the Menu can appear, which is written in CSS syntax@musicamante

Comment: No. QSS work on the widget, not on the whole context. They aren't part of "a web page", they are separate objects, and that concept is of utmost importance for "external" widgets: a menu is not "physically" part of the widget that creates it. Please be *very* aware of this: QSS are *based* on CSS, but widgets are not web pages. They may share similar concepts, but they are semantically *very* different, especially from the OS context. A widget (including a menu) is *actually* a ***separate*** window. Besides, just like the CSS2.1 implementation they're based on, they are mostly intended for ->

Comment: -> *displaying* purposes, not actual interaction. They're mostly static, their action is practically *just visual*, based on dynamic properties (*of the target object*) for which they have almost no control. *Real* interaction **must** be implemented on the logic side (C++/python), especially if you want to change properties on other widgets (like menu visibility). You want to show a menu when hovering a button? Then subclass it and override its [`enterEvent()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enterEvent) or install an event filter that checks for `QEvent.Enter`. QSS are ***not*** made for that.